# jQuery Autocomplete Appending Value to URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I am currently implementing an autocomplete module to my site which parses weather information from Weather Underground

```
$(function(request) {
    var cities = []; // setup empty array
    $.ajax({
      url : "http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?",
      query : request.term,
      dataType : "json",
      success : function(parsed_json) {
        for(i = 0; i < parsed_json['RESULTS'].length; i++) {
            cities.push(parsed_json['RESULTS'][i]['name'])
        }
      }
    });
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: cities
    });
});
```

Essentially, I populate an array called `cities` with the city names when the person types in their search query and it would send s request to Weather Underground's auto-complete API.

Using the variable `query : request.term`, I try to append the key value `query=[search term]` to the end of the `url`. However, when I check the console, it seems the `request.term` is always empty.

My question is - why is my input parameter empty for the text box?

The text box' `id` is `tags`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the widget on page load, then update its Array as you type. Since ajax is asynchronous, you need to update the autocomplete array inside the success callback

```
$(function () {
    var $input = $('#tags');
    $input.autocomplete({
        source: [] // Initially empty
    }).on('input', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?",
            data: { "query": $input.val() },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (parsed_json) {
                var cities = [];
                console.log(parsed_json);
                for (i = 0; i < parsed_json['RESULTS'].length; i++) {
                    cities.push(parsed_json['RESULTS'][i]['name'])
                }
                $input.autocomplete('option', 'source', cities);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d8zxhq2b/

Comment: Hi @acbabis - I am getting the following error when running your script: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined`

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Found my mistake; try again. Also, if my assumption in #1 is incorrect, you need to edit your answer explaining what `request` is supposed to be and where it's supposed to come from.

Comment: Hi acbabis. Thanks for the help. I actually didn't explain my question properly, I apologize. I don't mean to append my text box results to my URL, what I meant it is, have the text box's input be added to the `url` variable so I can perform an Ajax request to the Wunderground Autocomplete API depending on what I type in. My bad.

Comment: Thanks - that did return some results. However, I think because it doesn't send a request each time you type in a new character, I am only getting results for the first letter typed in. How can I change that?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage `input` event fires on each keypress. The ajax requests may be resolving out of order or may be getting rejected if you make too many. A robust solution may require you to delay requests and reject late arrivals; but that's out of scope for this question.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage IMO, the approach in Ricardo's answer makes better use of the `autocomplete` API by using a function to provide the array to the widget. I recommend incorporating both answers into your project.

Comment: I solved the issue :). Please use this in place of the `query` line - 

`data: { "query": $input.val() },`

Answer (score 1):

The "request" must be used with "source" object of autocomplete.

Here are an example:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
source: function (request, response) {
    $.get("http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?", {
        query: request.term
    }, function (data) {
        response($.map(results, function (data) {
                    return {
                        label: data.name,
                        value: data.value
                    }
                }));
}});
```

Hope it helps.